# Check box calling different methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a check box in a webpage in view and code related to it in controller. I have two methods to be called if the check box is checked or not.

This is my code:

```
function Saveabc() {
    var group = RetrieveGroup();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Administration/abc",
        data: group,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (abcID) {

        }
    });
}
```

Check box button:

```
<tr>           
    <input type ="checkbox" id="IsAssociation"/>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Create Group" onclick="Saveabc();" />
```

Controller:

```
public jsonresult abc() {}
public jsonresult abcdef() {}
```

If check box is checked and save button is clicked the function must call abcdef() and if the check box is not checked and saved abc() should be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Saveabc() {
    var group = RetrieveGroup();
    var isChecked = $('#IsAssociation').is(":checked")
    var url = (isChecked)
                 ? "/Administration/abc"
                 : "/Administration/abcdef";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: group,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (abcID) {    
        }
    });
}
```